# Cell coloring vba excel

Tags: vba, colors

I tried to write code to colour all cells in column D which are not in the format ow,ol,od.  However my code coloured all cells, regardless of the cell value. I could need your help.

[Data Column D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk1wU.jpg)

```
Sub colour()

For Z = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Cells(Z, 4) = "OW" And Cells(Z + 1, 4) = "OL" And Cells(Z + 2, 4) = "OA" Then
    Else
    Cells(Z, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
  End If
Next Z

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Cells(Z, 4) = "OW" And Cells(Z + 1, 4) = "OL" And Cells(Z + 2, 4) = "OA"
```

Your code checks (I even tested it) if 3 consecutive cells in a column have the values "OW", "OL" and "OA". For example if D1 = "OW" , D2 = "OL" and D3 = "OA" then the cell D1 won't get colored. In every other case it will.

If this isn't what you are looking for then try to elaborate your goal.

Comment: Thats right i want to check if D1 = "OW" , D2 = "OL" and D3 = "OA" if yes than do no colouring and if not than colour. For excample if           D1 = "OW" , D2 = "OL" and D3 = "OL". I really dont understand it because when i run the macro it colours every cell...

Comment: D1 = "OW" , D2 = "OL" and D3 = "OL".

You are not checking for that. Your code only doesn't color when the 3 cells have OW OL and OA in that specific order.